# DB2/400 hierarchical query with parent only where clause and parent-child ordering

Tags: sql, db2-400

I have a legacy DB2/400 DB running on IBMi (AS/400, iSeries). I am trying to query a table which refers to itself which models a help desk system consisting of 'cases'. Cases may have child cases (but child cases may not). Each case has a unique ID and also a parent ID (as well as lots of other fields). The parent ID field is blank if this is the parent (sometimes but not always it has a value of *PARENT), if it is a child it has the ID of the parent. Most cases do not have children, some cases have mulitple children (grandchildren not allowed).

The ordering is not so important except that I need child cases (if any) to follow their parent. I also need to set a where clause on the parents only to select by date and status. The children of the parent should always be included if the parent is - the where only applies to the parent. The ordering of the chilren is not important.

I  have been successful in selecting the records with the parent followed by the children (if any) but not in applying the where to the parent only. If I apply the where as in the example below then it applies to the parent AND the children:

```
SELECT id, parent, LEVEL AS level
    FROM  cases
    /*where ... */
    CONNECT BY parent = prior id
    order siblings by id;
```

I just need it to apply to the parent.

I have also tried using recursive common table expressions but I either didn't get the parents or got a cycle error. The test DB table I am using is not very clean and there are no constraints to enforce the rules.

Many of the RCTE examples have the idea of links through various records and defining a starting point. I don't have a starting point, I just want to select the parent records using certain criteria, then include all their children.

Any help much appreciated.

Example Cases table:

```
ID      Parent ID
-----------------
P1234
P1235
P1236
P1237
P1238
P1239
C993     P1235
C994     P1235
C995     P1238
C996     P1235
```

Expected result ordering (children within/below parents):

```
P1234
P1235
C993     P1235
C994     P1235
C996     P1235
P1236
P1237
P1238
C995     P1238
P1239
```

Thank you.

Comment: "...I don't have a starting point, I just want to select the parent records using certain criteria..." -- well, that's a starting point. The starting point does not need to be a single row, but can be a [big] set of rows.

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: @TheImpaler Thanks for taking a look. A simple example added.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I don't have the chance of testing the query shown below in DB2-400, so I'm showing an example in DB2-LUW. Maybe the query could require some tweaks if the syntax is not fully accepted in the AS/400.

You can do:

```
select * from t order by coalesce(parent_id, id), parent_id nulls first
```

Result:

```
 ID     PARENT_ID 
 ------ --------- 
 P1234            
 P1235            
 C993   P1235     
 C994   P1235     
 C996   P1235     
 P1236            
 P1237            
 P1238            
 C995   P1238     
 P1239
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=652c046d52538d226c07db0feb4b3545).

Comment: That is helpful thanks. As you kindly noted it was DB2 and DB2/400 (IBM i) doesn't seem to understand 'nulls first', but in my case that doesn't matter because (as mentioned) my DB does not have nulls but blanks in the parent _id and sometimes (but not always!) '*PARENT' . I modified your SQL to give: select * from t order by case parent_id when '' then id when '*PARENT' then id else parent_id end, parent_id - which did give the right results. The only issue was that if there happened to not actually be a parent then the child was still included. Probably just a test data issue.

Comment: Just a note. When you say: "...The only issue was that if there happened to not actually be a parent..."; I would recommend set a foreign key constraint between the child and the parent to prevent data corruption.